# Scrollbar appears for no reason

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Alright so what my problem is is that on my website, there is a scrollbar appearing to let the user scroll like 1cm to the right.

I want to completely remote it and have the chatbox and logo actually centered in the page.

The same happens on mobile devices, the whole thing is SLIGHTLY scrollable which makes it really annoying.

Is there any way I can fix it?

Thanks a lot!
Alex

Comment: Do you mean a horizontal scrollbar or a vertical scrollbar?  I tried this site on safari, chrome, and firefox, and only got a vertical scrollbar (which is there for obvious reasons, right?  Or am I not understanding?)

Comment: This is the scrollbar I am getting on every device i try to visit the site from: http://puu.sh/6MD6r.jpg

Comment: And if you have an iPhone, try it you will see what I mean!

Comment: I don't see a horizontal scrollbar either, in I.E. 8. (I know my browser is old and stupid; that's because I'm at work!) @AlexanderLozada and I were not signed in, I bet, so that might be a factor.

Comment: Oh, apologies!  Didn't even see that, I was focusing on the textbox.  Can we see some css?  I've seen this happen in my projects if I specify something like a margin/padding on the center box and then center it with margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I added overflow-x:hidden; in the body css. Now there is no scrollbar but on the device you can still move around. I guess it's mobile safari code I have to add.

Comment: Hmm, I looked into elements, and it seems you have a padding of 15px on either side of the body. Delete this and you'll be good.

I don't like overflow-x: hidden, because you can still scroll over with the middle mouse.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada --- http://puu.sh/6MDuV.jpg see how its not centered? I don't quite understand why that's happening :P

Comment: You have padding from the looks of it, yo.  check your body{} css.  See - http://puu.sh/6MDC0.png ?  It's giving it 30 extra pixels on top of the 100% width.  1 sec, I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of the Chrome inspector, you have added padding to the body which will push over any content.  Because your width of the body is already 100%, adding 15px of margin on either side will create 30 extra pixels of width on top of your already 100% width, creating that horizontal scrollbar.

Take a look at this JSfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/T52MM/1/  I've simulated padding with a large border value.  This is what your extra padding is doing to the body, it is pushing it over to the right and adding unneeded space, creating the horizontal scroll bar.

However, once you remove that padding, it will work correctly.  http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/T52MM/2/

You can remove just the side padding in css by typing `body{padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}` (It'll behave like this http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/T52MM/3/ )

Comment: No prob, remember to select the answer so this answer can help future questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have in body CSS a width of 100%.

I disabled it in chrome and the horizontal scroll bar was gone.

```
width: 100%;
```

Try removing that and see how it goes.